# Translating datediff LINQ query to SQL with Entity Framework Core and .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm working on reporting functionality that relates the number of records to the difference between order date and appointment date (e.g., I want to know how many people sign up two weeks in advance vs the day of).

I really want to do as much data grouping on SQL Server for performance reasons, which is why I try to convert the following LINQ query to SQL:

```
filtered.GroupBy(x => (x.AppointmentDate - x.CreatedOn).Days)
                           .Select(x => new BookingLeadTimeDbOutputDto
                           {
                               DateDiff = x.Key,
                               RecordsProcessed = x.Count()
                           });
```

That works perfectly when I try this with LINQPad, but throws an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated

when I try this in VS. The database I'm working in is the same in both cases, as well as .NET version (Core 3.1).

Here's LINQPad's SQL output:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime2 = '2018-07-10 00:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @p1 DateTime2 = '2020-07-10 00:00:00.0000000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RecordsProcessed], [t1].[value] AS [DateDiff]
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(Int,(CONVERT(BigInt,(((CONVERT(BigInt,DATEDIFF(DAY, [t0].[CreatedOn], [t0].[AppointmentDate]))) * 86400000) + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, [t0].[CreatedOn], [t0].[AppointmentDate]), [t0].[CreatedOn]), [t0].[AppointmentDate])) * 10000)) / 864000000000) AS [value], [t0].[AppointmentDate]
    FROM [ClientBookings] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[AppointmentDate] >= @p0) AND ([t1].[AppointmentDate] <= @p1)
GROUP BY [t1].[value]
```

I would assume that EF couldn't in principle translate this LINQ to SQL, but since it did in LINQPad I can't get what the problem might be, any ideas?

Comment: Because Linqpad uses LINQ-to-SQL by default.

Comment: Or you haven’t posted the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

if it is MS SQL server, ef has a special function DateDiffDay

```
filtered.GroupBy(x =>  EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.CreatedOn,x.AppointmentDate) )
                           .Select(x => new BookingLeadTimeDbOutputDto
                           {
                               DateDiff = x.Key,
                               RecordsProcessed = x.Count()
                           });
```

Comment: That did work for me, thanks a lot! Still curious why did the query I came up with not work in the project while it did in the LINQPad...